# Is $6 | 2a(3b+3)$ true $\forall a,b \in \Bbb Z$?

Tags: solution-verification, factoring

I have a homework question regarding unique factorisation, asking for me to find whether the following is true:

$6\;\mid\;2a(3b+3)\;\forall \text{ }a,b \in \Bbb Z$

I've tried the following:

$6\mid2a(3b + 3) $

$ =6\mid6ab + 6\color{red}a $

Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, the product of $6ab$ is divisible by 6, therefore $6\;\mid\;2a(3b+3)$ is true  for all $a,b \in \Bbb Z$

Does this constitute an adequate proof or should I approach this another way?

Comment: Its fine.......

Comment: You are almost there. $6ab+6=6(ab+1)$, therefore it is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Thanks! Is the $6(ab + 1)$ a form of induction to prove that this is true for values of $ab + 1$?

Comment: No. We say $a$ divides $b$ if there exists $n$ such that $b=an$.

Comment: Use `$\;$` instead of `$\text{ }$` for space and `$\mid$` and `$\nmid$` for $\mid$ and $\nmid$ respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$2a(3b+3) = 6ab+6\color{red}a.$$
Now you can simply write $$2a(3b+3) = \color{orange}6 \cdot (\color{blue}{ab+a}) + \color{green}0.$$

Comment: Whoops, can't believe I missed that one. Could you please explain the significance of the $+ 0$?

Comment: If the remainder of the division of $2a(3b+3)$ by $6$ is $0$, then $6$ divides $2a(3b+3)$.

Comment: I think usual one defines $u|v$ iff $\exists k \in \mathbb Z: \; v=ku$, and not $v=ku+0$.

Comment: $(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}.\; v = ku) \iff (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}.\; v = ku + 0).$